# How to get the email senders name from the contact form - Laravel Mail

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-7

How can i change the Mail Subject, Title and the senders name from the form input fields,

Here's my contact form

```
<h1>Contact</h1>
<form action="contact/store" method="post">
    @csrf
    <label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
<br>
<label>Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
<br>
<label>Message</label>
<textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here's my Mail controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->name;
    $email = $request->email;
    $textmessage = $request->message;

    $data = array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'textmessage' => $textmessage);
    Mail::send('mail', $data, function ($message) {
        $message->to('jareerzeenam.29@gmail.com', 'Email Title')->subject('Test Subject 2');
        $message->from('test@gmail.com', 'Test Name 2');
    });
    echo "HTML Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
}
```

Here's my mail.blade.php

```
    <h1>Hi, i'm {{ $name }}</h1>
<p>Email :{{ $email }}</p>
<p>Message : {{ $textmessage }}</p>
```

Here's how i get the email as

[image: email screen shot]

How can i get the name from the contact form input field to my email instead of the static name i have given in the controller, hope my question is understandable.

Comment: You mean, you want to get "From name" of mail?

Comment: Yes @MiteshRathod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to assign `name` and `email`, I didn't find subject, so I left it as default.

Try this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->name;
    $email = $request->email;
    $textmessage = $request->message;

    $data = array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'textmessage' => $textmessage);
    Mail::send('mail', $data, function ($message) use ($name, $email) {
        $message->to('jareerzeenam.29@gmail.com', 'Email Title')->subject('Test Subject 2');
        $message->from($email, $name);
    });
    echo "HTML Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
}
```

Comment: I tried the above codes and i got an error message saying 'Undefined variable: data' . Any thing to do in order to get rid of the error ? @STA

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
->to('jareerzeenam.29@gmail.com', 'Email Title')
```

use

```
->to([['mail' => 'jareerzeenam.29@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Email Title']])
```

So, to() accepts array of receivers, and a receiver can be an array with name and mail.

Comment: I tried the above code and i got this error "ErrorException
Array to string conversion" ?  @MuratTutumlu